# DataTrigger doesn't swap back

Tags: xaml, datatrigger

basically i have 2 ComboBoxes and i want to `isEnabled="false"` my secound `ComboBoxe2` as long as my first `ComboBoxe1.Selecteditem == null`

so i created the following `DataTrigger`

```
    <ComboBox Name="CB1"
              DisplayMemberPath="NameL"
              IsEnabled="{Binding isNew}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding selectedSpTyp}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding SpTypList}"/>

    <ComboBox Name="CB2"
              DisplayMemberPath="NameD"
              SelectedItem="{Binding selectedDesginvorlage}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding DesginvorlageList}">
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CB1.SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
    </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Binding` in your `DataTrigger` isn't set up correctly. You've assigned the `Binding` a `Path` of `CB1.SelectedItem` so it is looking at whatever the current `DataContext` is for a property named `CB1` and then a `SelectedItem` property on that object. You've also included an `UpdateSourceTrigger` setting which, while not breaking anything, is meaningless in this instance (it is used to determine when to push changes to the Source with a `TwoWay` or `OneWayToSource` binding usually on an input control).

To bind to another control within the same namescope use `ElementName` to specify the control and `Path` to specify the property:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CB1, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
```